# How to search for hyphen- oder underscore-separated words in Google Drive?

Tags: search, google-drive

For better compatibility, my filenames don't contain spaces. However Google Drive does not seem to support partial searching expect when separated by spaces.

For example, if my filename is "meeting-protocol", "meeting_protocol" or "meetingprotocol", a search for "protocol" does not find anything. It only gives me a result if the filename is "meeting protocol".

How can I get Google Drive to return search results for partial matches or at least for words separated by characters other than spaces like hyphens or underscores?

P.S.: Google Drive seems to have just changed this. I created empty text documents titled "this-is-a-mylongword-test" and "this_is_a_mylongword_test" and I could find both by searching for "mylongword". However I will not close this quite yet until I'm sure this is not a fluke but indeed the new default stable behavior. It still didn't find "longword" though, which is what the "duplicate" question is about.

Comment: Is this the website or android application?

Comment: @Mokubai: The website. I didn't know there is an android application.

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks for the link! The question is indeed similarto mine but it is nearly seven years old and the accepted answer actually doesn't answer the question, as it includes spaces in the filename. Maybe something has changed in the meantime. None of the other answers contain a comprehensive description as well. Also, partial matching is not exactly the same as hyphen-separated whole-word matching.